# Make loop only print a single value at a time

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How do I make:

```
c=5
for i in range(10):
    print(c)
    c+=1
```

so that instead of printing across several lines like:

```
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
```

In each loop it will go:

```
5
```

Then when it loops again it will overwrite the existing line with:

```
6
```

How do I go about that?

Comment: Use `yield` if you want to pause and resume the function. But it won't be like "in each loop, it will print", but instead "each time you call the generator it will resume the loop".

Comment: @Nishant Can you show with example?

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about _overwriting_ the output on a line. In that case, look into something like the *curses* library: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

Comment: Do you want to overwrite the existing line? If so you need to modify the question.

Comment: @jrd1 Yeah I want to print single digit on each loop.  When I try and install curses it gets no module: apparently "no direct Python for Windows port of curses exists."

Comment: @geeg: On the documentation for `curses`: 

_The Windows version of Python doesn’t include the curses module. A ported version called UniCurses is available. You could also try the Console module written by Fredrik Lundh, which doesn’t use the same API as curses but provides cursor-addressable text output and full support for mouse and keyboard input_

Comment: Okay @geeg. It looks like a duplicate then! Check the question linked.

Comment: @Nishant A large percentage of those solutions rely on time.sleep which is not good practise.

Answer (score 3):

In `python 3.3`, you can do like below

```
print(c , end="\r", flush=True)
```

Comment: this prints 14 for me ha

Comment: @geeg I have mentioned that above method would work only for python 3.3. Please check your python version.

Comment: I use Python 3.6.3.  Isn't 3.3 an older python version?  I'd imagine downgrading might cause issues with other libraries.

Comment: I have also tested above code for python 3.6.1

Comment: I think that you should clearly highlight that this only work in Python 3.3, because when you see that in Python3.3 works, you instantly think that this will work in higher versions.

Comment: @geeg 14 is the last value to be get printed in your case. If you want to see the change in value. please put sleep of few seconds after every iteration.

Answer (score -1):

To print text with a space instead of a newline at the end you can use the `end` parameter.

```
print("text", end=" ")
```

in python2 this can be achieved with a trailing comma:

```
print "text",
```

for Example,

```
c = 5
for i in range(10):
    print c,
    c += 1
```

Comment: I don't think that is what the question was asking for.

Comment: Feel free to [edit] with an updated response

Answer (score -1):

You can use carriage return (`"\r"`) to do the trick:

```
import time

c = 5
for i in range(10):
    print(c, end='\r')
    c += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```